# Change frame rate of FFmpeg output video in concat case

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a file `list_of_file_names.txt` which (for instance) has the content

```
file 'file_000.png'
file 'file_001.png'
...
```

I want to make a video with a frame rate of 5 frames per second from this sequence of image files. In an attempt to do so, I use the command

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 5 -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list_of_file_names.txt.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

which then gives me the error `Option framerate not found.`.

How do I set the frame rate to 5 frames per second without getting errors?

Comment: The [concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) is intended to literally stitch multiple files using the same codec together without needing to re-encode them. Changing frame rate does not really make sense in that case. Your example with multiple PNGs looks better suited for the [image2 filter](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)

Comment: Try to use -r 5 to set framerate

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `list_of_file_names.txt` should be

```
file 'file_000.png'
duration 0.2
file 'file_001.png'
duration 0.2
...
file 'file_099.png'
duration 0.2
file 'file_099.png'
```

in case of a 100 frames (notice that the last image is included twice, the second time without a duration, as mentioned on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow under the section 'Concat demuxer'.

And the command should be

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -safe 0 -y -f concat -i .\list_of_file_names.txt -r 5 output.mp4
```

under Windows 10.

Comment: This answer doesn't work if you have any repeated frames. FFmpeg will straight up ignore your duration and combine sequential identical frames. Result is a variable framerate video.